# Is there a way to make Thunderbird use the Mac OS X spell checker?

Tags: macos, thunderbird, spell-check

Is there a way to make Thunderbird use the Mac OS X systemwide spell checker instead of Thunderbird's own spell checker?

Comment: What you mean by spell checker because I have thunderbird 3.0.6 on my macbook and it has spell checker.

Comment: @Am1rr3z OSX has a built-in spell checker that works globally for every textbox in every program that choses to support it. Thunderbird does not. I wish it did. A global spell checker is great since it enables *every* program on my computer to know all the specialized vocabulary I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[No.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86886)